# The Dead Letter Queue does not display the originating topic name of the record

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, dead-letter, dlq

When processing records from multiple source topics in my sink connector, I've configured error handling to route erroneous records to a designated topic for analysis. However, despite enabling error logging and configuring a Dead Letter Queue (DLQ), the records in the DLQ do not include information about their originating topics. I added this lines for error handling to my connector:

```
    "errors.log.enable": "true",
    "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name":"dlq-test-sink-1",
    "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.replication.factor":1,
    "errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable":true,
    "errors.retry.delay.max.ms": 600000,
    "errors.retry.timeout": 1000000,
```

However, upon reviewing the records, I am unable to discern their originating topics. Additionally, the header of each record only displays a numerical identifier.

I want to determine the name of the topic from which the record originated.